# Inserting data in to matplotlib subplot Figures

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a CSV of data I and am trying to plot all of the data on the same row in this style:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,3,1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1,3,2)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(1,3,3)
```

How do insert the below data which I was previously plotting sequentially on top of each other in to the created figures above?

```
mru.plot(x='time', y='r1', color='black')
plt.ylabel('Roll', fontsize=18)
plt.xlabel('')
plt.title('MRU Primary Roll')

mru.plot(x='time', y='p1', color='black')
plt.ylabel('Pitch', fontsize=18)
plt.xlabel('')
plt.title('MRU Primary Pitch')

mru.plot(x='time', y='t1', color='black')
plt.ylabel('Tilt', fontsize=18)
plt.xlabel('')
plt.title('MRU Primary Tilt')
```

Comment: Give the correct ax to the `ax` keyword, like `mru.plot(..., ax=ax1)`

Comment: Works..Can you post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify on which ax it should be plotted with the `ax` keyword argument in `plot`. For example:

```
mru.plot(x='time', y='r1', color='black', ax=ax1)
```

Note that you probably will also have to use the Axes object for the rest of the formatting of the figure if you want to adjust the correct subplot:

```
mru.plot(x='time', y='r1', color='black', ax=ax1)
ax1.set_ylabel('Roll', fontsize=18)
ax1.set_xlabel('')
ax1.set_title('MRU Primary Roll')
```